# Codeigniter ical event not sending on gmail - Unable to load event data or getting as text

Tags: php, codeigniter, events, gmail, icalendar

I have tried below code to send ics event on codeigniter to gmail but getting as text. And If tried using header() or attach() I getting "unable to load request data". Can someone tell any possible way to fix this.

```
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:' . $event['end_event'] . '
UID:' . md5($event['title']) . '
DTSTAMP:' . time() . '
SUMMARY:' . addslashes($event['title']) . '
DTSTART:' . $event['start_event'] . '
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';


$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

  $config['protocol'] = 'ssmtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://ssmtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['smtp_user']    = 'mail@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';
        $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
        $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not   
        
        $this->email->initialize($config);


$this->email->from('from@myc2s.com', $from);
$this->email->to('to@gmail.com'); 
        
$this->email->subject('ICS');
$this->email->message($ical);  

$sendmessage = $this->email->send();
```

On trying below code I getting "unable to load request data"

```
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/calendar');
$this->email->attach($ical);
$sendmessage = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: I think you have a TYPO, this `$this->email->message($ical); ` should be this:  `$this->email->message($message);`

Comment: Oh my bad, posted the edited code. The same happening if $message passed.